# Avoid repetition of code in java using generic method

Tags: java, android

In my Android application I perform some actions related with my Room Database. These actions have to be done in background, this is why I use a threadExecutor. As you can see the code for both methods is almost the same and I was wondering if it would be possible to construct something generic to avoid this code repetition.

```
public void addOperation(Operation operation, AddOperationInteractor.CallBack callback)
{
    Interactor interactor = new AbstractInteractor(ThreadExecutor.getInstance())
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                operationRepository.addNewOperation(operation);
                callback.onAddOperationSuccess();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                callback.onAddOperationSuccess();
            }
        }
    };

    interactor.execute();
}

public void deleteOperation(Operation operation, RemoveOperationInteractor.CallBack callback)
{
    Interactor interactor = new AbstractInteractor(ThreadExecutor.getInstance())
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                operationRepository.removeOperation(operation);
                callback.onRemoveOperationSuccess();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                callback.onRemoveOperationSuccess();
            }
        }
    };

    interactor.execute();
```

Comment: so ..; during the adding or removing an exception is thrown, and your logic is to communicate to the using service that it was a success? There is no duplicate code here, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: What I mean is that the only code that changes is the code inside the run() method. And I have about 10 methods with the same structure. I was looking for a way of avoiding this code repetition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no repetition in your code. To reduce boilerplate code, try a lambda:

```
public void addOperation(Operation operation, AddOperationInteractor.CallBack callback) {
    ThreadExecutor.getInstance().execute(() -> {
        try {
            operationRepository.addNewOperation(operation);
        }
        finally {
            callback.onAddOperationSuccess();
        }
    });
}

public void deleteOperation(Operation operation, RemoveOperationInteractor.CallBack callback) {
    ThreadExecutor.getInstance().execute(() -> {
        try {
            operationRepository.removeOperation(operation);
        }
        finally {
            callback.onRemoveOperationSuccess();
        }
    });
}
```

Now there is only 1 repeating line, to invoke the ThreadExecutor.

Alternatively pass callbacks to a helper method:

```
public void addOperation(Operation operation, AddOperationInteractor.CallBack callback) {
    execute(()-> operationRepository.addNewOperation(operation),
            ()-> callback.onAddOperationSuccess());
}

public void deleteOperation(Operation operation, RemoveOperationInteractor.CallBack callback) {
    execute(()-> operationRepository.removeOperation(operation),
            ()-> callback.onRemoveOperationSuccess());
}

private void execute(Runnable action, Runnable onSuccess) {
    ThreadExecutor.getInstance().execute(() -> {
        try {
            action.run();
            onSuccess.run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.warn(e);
            onSuccess.run();
        }
    }
}
```